# Plot function with Safari: numbers from Axis squished in the corner

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, front-end, labeling

I'm using the Mathematica cloud service and want to plot a function like this.

(This is the basic Example from the Documentation)

[image: This is the basic Example from the Documentation]

But on my browser the resulting Plot looks like this.

(an image of my Polt)
[image: an image of my Polt]

What is happening here, and why are the numbers from my axis squished in to the corner?

I tried this in different Notebooks and I don't know what to do.

Also, I just started using Mathematica so the answer to my problem could be obvious, if so PLEASE link the relevant documentation.

Edit:

Per request I executed `$Version` this is my result:

```
12.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 22, 2021)
```

2. Edit:

This Bug appeared on the Safari browser with MacOS.

**For a quick Fix, just use a different Browser.**

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error.  Are you saying that a new notebook containing only `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 6 Pi}]` always produces the second figure?  `Out[35]` suggests that your notebook contains many lines of code that already have been executed that may be causing the problem.

Comment: Sadly yes, but good point. I will replace the picture of the plot with a picture of a new notebook.

Comment: Execute `$Version` and add the entire result to your question.  By the way, have you encountered other strange results recently.

Comment: Can you try in a different browser? This sounds like an issue somebody was telling me about with the latest version of Safari on macOS.

Comment: Not really, but im quite new here so i don't know what's strange or not

Comment: Im on Safari with MacOS, and with the Crome browser it works.

Comment: By the way, is changing the browser a sufficient answer to a problem ? Or should I leave the question open ?

Comment: Peter, did you report this to Wolfram Support? If not, can you, please, report this to them? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this issue as a Bug and it has been forwarded to the Developer.

**The quick fix for now is just to use another browser.**